# File count discrepancy

Tags: powershell

I'm using Powershell to get a list of files stored on a server.  After all was said and done, I did a comparison using Windows Properties.  I'm noticing a discrepancy between the amount of files.  What could this be due to?

Here is the code I used - it came back with **70453** rows/files

```
Get-ChildItem  \\server\share -recurse | Where {!$_.PsIsContainer} | 
Select-Object Directory, Name, Length, CreationTime, LastWriteTime | 
ConvertTo-Csv | Tee -FilePath "H:\CSV - All Files\AllFiles.csv" | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

When I did the Windows Properties on the share, it came back with **72308** files (12,589 folders)

Comment: system file might be filter with Powershell

Comment: I think that was it!  After googling how to fix it, I found the -force command.  It came up with the correct number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the same code as above, but adding the -force command (after googling how to search for system files using Powershell).  The numbers match up.